# React Native - Navigate to detail screen by clicking on item in flatList?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I'm rendering names out of an API by using flatList. I'm then trying to make each item clickable and display more information about that person they clicked on, and i'm not sure how to go about things. Some posts i've read here on Stackoverflow that has links to examples are now dead and not useable.

I'm using DrawerNavigation and i will try my best to include the code needed, i have all my Screens in the app.js file.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerPosition="right">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Players" component={PlayersScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
 
  );
};
```

Each Screen has its own function bellow this, here is the PlayerScreen example which is the one containing the list rendered by flatList.

```
function PlayersScreen( { navigation } ) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://***.**.***.**:3000/players',
   { credentials: "same-origin",
   headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
  },
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);
  return (
      <View style={{marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()) }>
            <Text>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.Name}</Text>
            )}
          />
      </View>
   
  );
```

---EDIT----

My flatlist currently look like this

```
  <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.Name}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={{fontSize: 32, color: 'white'}} onPress={() => alert("clicked")}>{item.Name}</Text>
            )}
          />
```

So now how do i handle that onPress to navigate to a component that will display more information about the name selected?

Any help is appreciated, cheers,
N

Comment: If you want to navigate to a new screen you have to pass `() => {navigation.navigate('Player', {data: item})` to the onPress function.  

But you don't have another screen named "Player" in your Drawer Navigator, thats why I assumed you want to stay on the same Screen "Players" and unfold the information of the player in the flatlist when somebody presses on it.  Can you clarify if you really want to navigate to another screen? In that case you would have to build a new screen 'Player'.

Comment: Oh bad information from my part. I'd like to open it in a new component so i get a new screen and only veiw the selected item on the next component. I'm not sure how to send the ID/key from the flatList so that the component i arrive to after click will only show info about that certain person.

Comment: In that case you can use `() => {navigation.navigate('Player', {data: item})}`
in your `onPress()`. The `{data: item}` object transfers the item to your new screen, where you can extract it with `route.params.data`. Have a look here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: Hi, i tried adding this line to my flatList:  <Text onPress={() => {navigation.navigate(DetailsScreen, {data: item})}}>{item.Name}</Text> 
And i also have this in app.js 

function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) { 
/* code */
}

I get : The action NAVIGATE with Payload undefined was not handled by any navigator, and they ask if i really have a screen named "DetailsScreen".

Comment: Hi again, i saw i had to add it to the drawer, how ever i will work around that later to be able to use details without it showing in Drawer menu. Now how ever i do get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.itemid)"

Comment: This is because you have to use the Drawer to be able to access the route params. I really reccomend you to read more of the documantation.

Comment: I have done so now, and it seem to be working, thanks for you help! How can i tag your comment as a answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you don't really want to navigate to the detail screen, but rather unfold a detail component which is residing in the same screen as the flatlist.

If you really want to navigate to the detail screen, you'd have to pass a function with a call to`navigation.navigate` to every item inside the `renderItem` property.

Like this:

```js
<FlatList
 data={data}
 keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate('ItemDetail', {data: item}
     }
   )}>
      <Text>
       +
      </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
/>
```

If you  want to pass a component, you'd have to do something like this:

```js
<FlatList
 data={data}
 keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
   <ItemDetail item={item}/>    
  )}
/>
```

and then handle the click on "+" inside your new `ItemDetail` component. Of cause you don't have to create a new component, you also can define all the markup inline, but it is cleaner and reusable if you use a new component.

Comment: I get a blank screen when I do this

Comment: @Ele:  Getting error: 'navigation' is not defined.